# Cursor not going to the next textfield in UITableView while pressing the next button in swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am using the single cell with a uitextfield to show a form containing the username , email id, phone number. But i want to move the cursor to the next field while pressing the next button.

I am using the code like this:

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let userNameCell = self.profileManagement!.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? RegistrationFieldTableViewCell!
    let emailIDCell = self.profileManagement!.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) as? RegistrationFieldTableViewCell!

    if textField == userNameCell {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      emailIDCell?.becomeFirstResponder()
      return false
    } else if textField == emailIDCell {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

The cell for row at index path code goes like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let regCell = profileManagement.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"regFirstCell", for: indexPath)as? RegistrationFieldTableViewCell
    regCell?.registrationField.tag = indexPath.row
    regCell?.registrationFieldImage.image = fieldImages[indexPath.row]
    let nameFields = NSLocalizedString( regFieldsNames[indexPath.row], comment: "")
    regCell?.registrationField.placeholder = nameFields
    regCell?.registrationField.autocorrectionType = .no
    regCell?.registrationField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    regCell?.showPassword.isHidden = true
    //Swith case for giving keypad to textfields
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = self.name
      regCell?.registrationField.isSecureTextEntry = false
    case 1:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = self.emailId
      regCell?.registrationField.textColor = UIColor.black
      regCell?.registrationField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    case 2:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = self.civilId
      regCell?.registrationField.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
      regCell?.registrationField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    case 3:
      regCell?.registrationField.text = "+965 \(self.phoneNumber)"
      regCell?.registrationField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    case 4:
      regCell?.registrationField.isSecureTextEntry = true
      regCell?.registrationField.text = "abhijith123"
      regCell?.showPassword.isHidden = true
      regCell?.registrationField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    default:
      print("Something else")
    }
    return regCell!
  }
```

But while pressing the next button on keyboard it is not switchin to the next text field. Why is it so? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Don't you need to set `regCell?.registrationField.delegate = self`?

Comment: @beyowulf why we need to do this?

Comment: `func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool` is a delegate method of `UITextFieldDelegate`, it only gets called if `UITextField`'s `delegate` property is set.